# Isomorphism between two quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

I am self studying Artin's algebra and stuck with this exercise which asks 'Are $\mathbb{Z}[x] /\langle x^2 +7 \rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x] /\langle 2x^2 + 7\rangle$ *isomorphic*?'

My sense tells answer is no but to
show non-isomorphism , we should execute one property that one ring has and other hasn't ... I couldn't figure out the property... Thanks in advance for any help/ hints ..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

I think you're right.   The first ring $\Bbb Z[X]/(x^2+7)\cong \Bbb Z[\alpha] $ where $\alpha^2+7=0$.  As abelian groups,  we have $\Bbb Z[X]/(x^2+7)\cong\{a+b\alpha \mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\}\cong \Bbb Z^2$, since we can divide any polynomial by $x^2+7$ and get a remainder of degree less than $2$.

This is not true in the case of $\Bbb Z[X]/(2x^2+7)$.  We can't perform division of any polynomial in $\Bbb Z[X]$ by $2x^2+7$, because of its not being monic.  In particular,  we can  only divide by $2x^2+7$, inside $\Bbb Z[X]$, when the dividend is a polynomial whose leading coefficient is a multiple of $2$.  (Apparently you learn more about this sort of thing when you study *localization*.)  But the upshot is that you get some higher degree polynomials.

In fact,  we can conclude that $\Bbb Z[x]/(f)$ is not a finitely generated abelian group if $f$ is not monic.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2230921/1070376).   So it can't be isomorphic as an abelian group to $\Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: Do you want to say isomorphic rings preserves division rule ? I couldn't clearly understand what is the relationship between doing division and isomorphism here. Also I want to know  about the element of the ring Z[x] /<2x^2 + 7> whereas you told element of Z[x] /<x^2 + 7> will be of the form a+b€ where €^2 + 7 = 0.

Comment: Yeah I don't know a canonical form for $\Bbb Z[X]/(2x^2+7)$ because of not being able to do that division.   Sorry I couldn't be a little more rigorous.   I'll look into it.  In fact, it isn't finitely generated.   See this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2230921/1070376

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+7)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as rings. You want to specify that this is an isomorphism of abelian groups and that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x^2+7)$ is not finitely generated as abelian group.

Comment: @egreg thanks.   I made a mistake.   So, the problem is about rings; and,  we'll do it by proving they're not isomorphic as groups.   Correct?

Comment: @Cpc If you prove that the underlying abelian groups are not isomorphic, then the rings cannot be isomorphic (as rings) and the proof is good. Note that both rings are finitely generated (as rings), so what notion of “finitely generated” is used should be mentioned.

Comment: Yes, nontrivial localizations invert a nonunit so they cannot be integral (see the Remark in my answer). More generally every proper ideal survives in an integral extension, and this property can be used to *characterize* integral extensions - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57702/242).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $  Easy way: only one ring has a [sense of parity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242) (i.e. an image $\cong \Bbb Z/2).\,$

---

**Or** $\ \underbrace{\frac{1}2\in \Bbb Z[x]/(2x^2\!+\!7)}_{\small\textstyle 2(x^2\!+\!4)=1}\,$ but $\frac{1}2\not\in \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2\!+\!7)\,$ else $\,2w = 1\underset{\rm Norm}\Longrightarrow 4w\bar w = 1\in \Bbb Z.\,$

**Remark** $ $ Above a discriminating property is *integrality*. A *crucial* property of *integral* ring extensions is that they don't alter unit properties in the base ring, i.e. a nonunit $\,r\in R\,$ remains a nonunit in any integral extension ring $S\,$ (so they cannot introduce *fractions* like $1/2\,$ above). For example, this may allow us to deduce that Diophantine equations in $\Bbb Z$ are unsolvable by deducing a parity contradiction $\,2\mid 1\,$ in some convenient extension ring of algebraic integers. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137826/242) for further discussion.

Comment: 1/2 belongs to the first quotient ring but doesn't belong to next. Ok , but to be explicit, how does it imply that the aforesaid rings are non-isomorphic ? Also how can I take norm in this ring ? I haven't studied yet. Any help ?

Comment: [Ring homs $\,h\,$ preserve roots of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/667881/242), so a root of $2x=1$ *persists* as a root  in any isomorphic ring, i.e. $\,1= h(1) = h(2x) = 2h(x).\,$ The norm of $w = a+b\sqrt{-7}$ is $\,N(w) := w\bar w = a^2+7b^2\,$ where $\,\bar w = a-b\sqrt 7\,$ is the conjugate.  It's immediate that the [norm is multiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12216/242) $\,N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha) N(\beta).\ \ $